# Is there an `rc` file for the command line calculator `bc`?

Tags: bash, command-line, bc

Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324157/how-to-get-a-decimal-number-when-dividing-in-bc), I would like to default `scale = 2` every time I start `bc` from the command line (or from inside `vim`). However, `man bc` did not mention a `.bcrc` file, and when I experimentally created `~/.bcrc`, it did not have any noticeable effect.

Is there an environmental variable or `rc` file that can be set to give default options to `bc`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With GNU bc, you can set the environment variable `BC_ENV_ARGS` to be the name of a file that bc should read on startup.

Add the following to your `.bashrc` file :

```
export BC_ENV_ARGS=$HOME/.config/bcrc
```

if you need to load the standard math library, you can do this :

```
export BC_ENV_ARGS="-l $HOME/.config/.bcrc"
```

and you get a `.bcrc` like you wish.

Comment: `man bc` - Sect. "Environment Variables": http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bc.1.html#contenttoc3

Comment: plus one for the hint to the standard math lib.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of environment variables, I created an alias

```
alias bc="bc -l .bcrc"
```

and that loads the file .bcrc when I run bc.